# Fastest way to interpolate xy values ​for a given z on a 3d line

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, line, interpolation

I have a series of lines in 3d of which I know for each one of them the vertices x and z that compose them.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcr6Y.png)

What I need is to get for each line the xy coordinates given a z coordinate contained in that line. Numerically I know how to solve it, however I would like to find in python the fastest / most efficient way to carry out this task.

For example, given a line whose xyz values ​​I have stored in the following way:

```
>>> arr = array([[  6.04691088e+05,   4.11484364e+06,  -7.35610000e+00],
   [  6.04671604e+05,   4.11484372e+06,  -7.00000000e+00],
   [  6.04665386e+05,   4.11484374e+06,  -6.83720000e+00],
   [  6.04659607e+05,   4.11484376e+06,  -6.69120000e+00],
   [  6.04633141e+05,   4.11484387e+06,  -6.00000000e+00],
   [  6.04615502e+05,   4.11484394e+06,  -5.41870000e+00],
   [  6.04604279e+05,   4.11484398e+06,  -5.00000000e+00],
   [  6.04599722e+05,   4.11484400e+06,  -4.69160000e+00],
   [  6.04585486e+05,   4.11484406e+06,  -4.00000000e+00],
   [  6.04585333e+05,   4.11484406e+06,  -3.99290000e+00],
   [  6.04584247e+05,   4.11484406e+06,  -3.93210000e+00],
   [  6.04567577e+05,   4.11484413e+06,  -3.00000000e+00],
   [  6.04558717e+05,   4.11484416e+06,  -2.41210000e+00],
   [  6.04553510e+05,   4.11484419e+06,  -2.06660000e+00],
   [  6.04552563e+05,   4.11484419e+06,  -2.00000000e+00],
   [  6.04552018e+05,   4.11484419e+06,  -1.96420000e+00],
   [  6.04537647e+05,   4.11484425e+06,  -1.00000000e+00],
   [  6.04530721e+05,   4.11484428e+06,  -5.93300000e-01],
   [  6.04519556e+05,   4.11484432e+06,   0.00000000e+00],
   [  6.04519355e+05,   4.11484432e+06,   0.00000000e+00],
   [  6.04518720e+05,   4.11484432e+06,   0.00000000e+00],
   [  6.04518556e+05,   4.11484432e+06,   0.00000000e+00],
   [  6.04518296e+05,   4.11484433e+06,   0.00000000e+00],
   [  6.04516286e+05,   4.11484433e+06,   5.36200000e-01],
   [  6.04514899e+05,   4.11484434e+06,   8.77000000e-01],
   [  6.04514371e+05,   4.11484434e+06,   1.00000000e+00],
   [  6.04513926e+05,   4.11484434e+06,   1.12940000e+00],
   [  6.04511400e+05,   4.11484435e+06,   2.00000000e+00],
   [  6.04509132e+05,   4.11484436e+06,   2.38240000e+00],
   [  6.04508615e+05,   4.11484436e+06,   2.50000000e+00],
   [  6.04507578e+05,   4.11484437e+06,   2.68050000e+00],
   [  6.04506375e+05,   4.11484437e+06,   2.91140000e+00]])
```

I want to obtain the interpolated xy coordinates for any z, for example 1.38, so that:

```
>>> intrp3line(arr,z_value=1.38)
[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],...,[xn,yn]]
```

It should return a list with all pairs of xy coordinates interpolated to achieve the given z.

Almost all the information I have found on interpoolation is to solve the opposite problem, that is, interpolate the coordinate z a for a given xy, but very little relative to the problem I pose. On the other hand, considering that I have the N lines with their xyz coordinates and a list of N z values ​​(one for each line), I would also like to know if there is any way to optimize the interpolation by treating the set of lines instead to iterate one by one.

Comment: Won't 1d interpolate z to x and then z to y do what you want?

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is using scikit-learn's LinearRegression like so.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

line = LinearRegression().fit(arr[:,2].reshape(-1, 1), arr[:,0:2])
```

To now obtain points you can just use `line.predict`:

```
z = np.linspace(-8,2,10**5)
xy = line.predict(z.reshape(-1, 1))
```

This takes ~1.26ms for 10^5 `z` values and seems to scale approximately linearly.

And you can plot it too.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig, auto_add_to_figure=False)
fig.add_axes(ax)
ax.view_init(elev=0, azim=0)#
ax.scatter(arr[:,0],arr[:,1],arr[:,2])
ax.plot(xy[:,0], xy[:,1], z)
```

[image]